# Filter Records In An Excel Spreadsheet By Matching Numbers In Another Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, comparison

I have website logs (tab-delimited text files) that contain constituent information (name, e-mail, etc...).  I import those logs into my [Raiser's Edge](https://www.blackbaud.com/fundraising-and-relationship-management/raisers-edge) database using [ImportOmatic](http://www.omaticsoftware.com/Solutions/TheRaisersEdge/ImportOmatic.aspx).  ImportOmatic will give me an exception log that shows records that didn't get imported.  Note that this isn't a question about Raiser's Edge or ImportOmatic (although it would be nice if the ImportOmatic exception log actually had the data that didn't get imported, instead of just a line number).

Example website log:

```
ImportID    KeyInd  FirstName   LastName    OrgName AddrImpID   AddrInfoSrc PrefAddr    AddrSendMail    AddrLines   AddrCity    AddrState   AddrZip AddrCountry ConsCode    PhoneAddrImpID2 PhoneNumber2    PhoneType2
InternetI201303999  I   Joshua  Jackson     InternetA201303999  Internet    Yes Yes 194 Notch Ln.   Reeds Spring    MO  65737   UNITED STATES   PARTNER InternetA201303999  jj@anti-exe.com E-Mail
```

Example exception log:

```
Line 1: Data too long for field: Max length = 3 for State [Object: 'CConstitAddress', PK: '-1', Import ID: '', Desc: '194 Notch Ln., Reeds Spring', Field: 'State', Value: 'Missour'] -->BBREAPI.CRecordClass.Save()-->ImportOM.CImport.Process()
```

In this particular instance, I misspelled Missouri (purposefully) which resulted in an exception.

I import the website log into one worksheet and the exception log into another worksheet (same file).  Excel gives the website log line numbers (my record would be line 2, because the header is line 1).  I import the exception log as a space-delimited (I guess I could use :-delimited, as well) text file (my exception is Line 1, as it doesn't import the header).  I should be able to do a formula to strip the : (`=LEFT(B1, LEN(B1)-1)`) and then add 1 (`=B1+1`), so that I have a column of line numbers that should match the line numbers that Excel gave the website log.  If there is no way to match the exception's line number column to Excel's created line numbers, I could always create an additional column and just have it fill with a series of numbers.

What I'm wanting to do is, somehow, use the exception log's `Line x` as a filter to show only those records that need to be manually entered.  I'm thinking like a reverse-filter (hiding the good data and showing the bad data).

Obviously, I haven't gotten it working (or else I wouldn't ask).  Am I going about it all wrong?  I'm sure this CAN be done, but it's eluding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list of errors is on Sheet2 in ColA (one line per cell, no need to split up on ":"), you can add a column to your imported data using something like this as a formula:

```
=ISERROR(MATCH("Line " & ROW()-1 & ":*",Sheet2!A:A,0))
```

Output:

```
TRUE  --> was imported
FALSE --> had an error
```

Comment: That is excellent.  I still haven't wrapped my head around it, but it is reporting the records, correctly.  I was able to filter that column and remove TRUE.  Now, I have only the records that I'm wanting to see.

Comment: There were multiple things, in that answer, that I didn't know existed or how to do.  I had seen `MATCH()` or `ROW()` and I didn't really understand the `A:A` array idea (I had seen that with other functions, but just didn't get it).  This is another, useful, tool in my belt.